# ASP.net GridView Horizontal Scrolling Issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, asp.net, mobile, gridview

I am facing an issue in iphone related to my mobile website that has been developed in asp.net 3.5

referring to screenshot of Cart area:
[image]

while viewing same grid inside desktop browser it shows scroll but in iPhone in does not and rest of area gets disappeared.

Gridview Code:

```
<div class="tabularDataContainer">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabularData">
        <tr class="tableH">
            <td width="39%" align="left" valign="top" class="tableH tableHL"><p>Workshop Name</p></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="1%"class="tableHD">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="19%" align="left" valign="top" class="tableH"><p>Date</p></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="1%"class="tableHD">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="19%" align="left" valign="top" class="tableH"><p>Attendee Name </p> </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="1%"class="tableHD">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10%" align="left" valign="top" class="tableH"><p>City</p></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="1%"class="tableHD">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" valign="top" class="tableH tableHR"><p>Amount</p></td>
       </tr>
    </table> 
<asp:GridView ID="grdCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="<br /> &nbsp;The Cart is Empty" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false" GridLines="None" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanging ="GrdCartRowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdCartDatabound" DataKeyNames="wName,Date, sdat, endt, wDates, AttendeeName"    >
                                        <Columns >

                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate >
                                        <div style="width:100%; height:60px;">
                                        <div style="position:relative; width:100%;">
                                        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; width:100%;" id="Container" runat="server" >
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabularDataRounded" >

                                        <tr class="cartD">
                                        <td width="39%" align="left" valign="top">
                                            <table width="100%">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="middle" width="5%" style="border-bottom:none;" class="cartcross"><p><asp:LinkButton id="lb_DeleteItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select" ><img src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete" class="del" width="100%" height="100%"></asp:LinkButton ></p></td>
                                                <td align="left" valign="middle"  width="95%" style="border-bottom:none;"><p><asp:DropdownList ID="ddl_wshops" runat="server" DataTextField="wName" cssclass="cartddl" style="display:block;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_AddNewWorkShop_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  >
                                                </asp:DropdownList></p></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>                                </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="1%" ></td>
                                        <td width="19%" align="left" valign="middle" ><p><asp:DropdownList ID="ddl_wdat" runat="server" cssclass="cartddldat" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ChangeDateInItem"  >
                                                </asp:DropdownList></p></td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="19%" align="left" valign="middle" ><p><asp:DropdownList ID="listbox_wAttendee" runat="server" cssclass="cartddldat" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChangeAttendeeInItem"   >
                                                </asp:DropdownList> </p></td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="10%" align="left" valign="middle" ><p><%#Eval("City")%></p></td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="10%" align="right" valign="middle" style="padding-right:15px"><p>$<%#Eval("Amount")%></p></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div>
```

any one guide me how to resolve this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up this issue just using

"overflow:scroll" property on gridview container, i searched alot this problem but i found nothing.

using above property iPhone allows you to scroll horizontally with two finger left or right ward, but in android or other phones nothing happens with two fingers LOL.